# Displaying memory in rows and columns, with starting address of each row displayed at the beginning of each line

Tags: c++, class, rows, member-functions

I'm currently writing a program which uses a class to simulate the operation of an 8-bit microcontroller. I had to create 5 member functions - setPC, show, loadFile, step and constructor. I'm having difficulty with a few aspects of the program but at the minute, specifically the show member function. This is what I have so far:

```
void cpu::show(void)
```

{

```
cout << "AccA = " << hex << static_cast<int>(AccA) << endl;

cout << "AccB = " << hex << static_cast<int>(AccB) << endl;

cout << "PC = " << hex << static_cast<int>(PC) << endl;

cout << "SP = " << hex << static_cast<int> (SP) << endl;

cout << "X = " << static_cast<int> (X) << endl;

cout << "Memory = " << hex << Memory << endl;
```

}

This member function is supposed to display the contents of the registers and memory in 2-digit hexadecimal format. It is supposed to display the memory in 16 rows and columns, with the starting address of each row displayed at the beginning of each line (the rest of the line can then be blank). I'm unsure of how to display the contents of memory in rows and columns. I'd appreciate any pointers in how to do this.

Here is the header file for the program:

```
#ifndef CPU_H
#define CPU_H

#define MEMSIZE 256

class cpu
{
private:
  unsigned char AccA;
  unsigned char AccB;
  unsigned char PC;
  unsigned char SP;
  unsigned char X;
  bool Z;
  unsigned char Memory[MEMSIZE];
public:
  cpu();
  void loadFile(const char *fileName);
  void setPC(unsigned char aAddress);
  bool step(void);
  void show(void);
};

#endif // CPU_H
```

Comment: What do you expect out of `hex << static_cast<int>(AccA)`?

Comment: Memory is where your data supposed to be stored? If yes, Did you intend to make it one dimension as array of chars and not two dimension as array of arrays of chars?

Comment: The value that is in AccA. I was having issues with loading a hex value into the program counter (PC) and it would output as a symbol - setting it as a static_cast<int> output it as hex.

Comment: @Sanaa Are you actually asking about how to format the `Memory` output that rows & columns way correctly?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, how to display the Memory in rows and columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm unsure of how to display the contents of memory in rows and columns.

Supposed you meant how to output the section for the `Memory` array, you should use a loop like this:

```
 bool print_address = true;
 std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
 for(size_t i = 0; i < MEMSIZE; ++i) {
     if(print_address) {
          std::cout << (void*)&Memory[i] << ' ';
          print_address = false;         
     }
     std::cout << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(Memory[i]) << ' ';         
     if(((i + 1) % 16) == 0) {
         print_address = true;
         std::cout << std::endl;
     }
 }
```

prints a pattern like

```
0x7fff95c1a410 06 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a420 78 12 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a430 08 a6 c1 95 ff 7f 00 00 18 a6 c1 95 ff 7f 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a440 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 74 e7 08 af 46 7f 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a450 01 00 00 00 46 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a460 48 07 21 ae 46 7f 00 00 28 79 07 af 46 7f 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a470 e0 73 07 af 46 7f 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a480 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 60 00 00 00 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a490 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 35 52 09 af 46 7f 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a4a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a4 c1 95 ff 7f 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a4b0 b8 12 60 00 00 00 00 00 60 09 40 00 00 00 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a4c0 d4 13 60 00 00 00 00 00 a8 38 24 ae 46 7f 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a4d0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a4e0 00 10 60 00 00 00 00 00 bd 0c 40 00 00 00 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a4f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60 0c 40 00 00 00 00 00 
0x7fff95c1a500 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 38 0b 40 00 00 00 00 00
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/628312107bed77c6)

Comment: I tried this, but the output wasn't the same. Some lines were longer than others and there were a few random symbols amongst the numbers

Comment: @Sanaa Well, I can't tell what's wrong with your actual code without seeing it (that might be worth another question asking for what you actually have now). The live demo link proves that this works under _normal circumstances_ and within the constraints you were giving for the output format.

Comment: @Sanaa As mentioned, it might be better **to ask another question** for what you have now, instead of creating a moving target, possibly invalidating the existing answers.

Comment: @Sanaa Apparently you missed my recent corrections for the code sample given in my answer. Check what's different from your attempt now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good [**tutorial**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm)

One of the basic two dimensional data structures is an array of arrays. This is how you *declare* a multidimensional array:

```
type arrayName [ x ][ y ];
```

Tnd this is how you *initially populate it* with data:

```
   int a[3][4] = {  
 {0, 1, 2, 3} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
 {4, 5, 6, 7} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
 {8, 9, 10, 11}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
};
```

[image]

And this is how you *access* its data:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   // an array with 5 rows and 2 columns.
   int a[5][2] = { {0,0}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6},{4,8}};

   // output each array element's value                      
   for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
      for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
      {
         cout << "a[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
         cout << a[i][j]<< endl;
      }

   return 0;
}
```